How to get selected value from select list by javascript in asp.net c#
As per my question, I didn't get selected value (it showing null value only) when select the list from select dropdownlist.
Following is the .aspx code
<select id="cmb_year" runat="server" onselect="loadCounties()"></select>
<script>
    $('#<%=cmb_year.ClientID%>').editableSelect()
</script>
 <asp:Label ID="lbl_id" runat="server" Text="demo"  ></asp:Label>

 <script>
    function loadCounties() {
        selectElement = document.querySelector('#cmb_year');
        output = selectElement.value;
        document.querySelector('#lbl_id').textContent = output;
        alert(output);
    }
</script>

Here is the aspx.cs code
service.BindHTMLDropdownList(cmb_year, "tbl_year", "year", "Id", "order by Id desc");

I tried many things but didn't work correctly. Above code is my latest try.

Here is another copy of this question : How to get value from editableSelect() by jquery in asp.net c#
